# Ibus-Anthy not working in 16.04

Tags: 16.04, keyboard, keyboard-layout, ibus, japanese

I want to write in hiragana Japanese letters

I'm using ubuntu 16.04 LTS

I installed ibus-anthy using `sudo apt-get installed ibus-anthy`

I also made ibus as default in language support and added ibus anthy in as text input in ibus prefrences

Now Anthy appears in the language icon and i can switch to it using my shortcuts but when i start typing system uses the previous language (which is Arabic in my system)

What should i do?

Comment: Which input mode are you using?

Comment: I found the solution ... I have to logout and login after adding the anthy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem solved

Every thing is okay just after I logout and login again

It looks like system should see it in the startup ... I don't know why but it is fine now

Comment: I see now that you added Anty in _IBus Preferences_. Actually, in Ubuntu you should normally not use IBus Preferences, but instead add the input sources via _System Settings -> Text Entry_. (And after having installed Anthy, a relogin would have been needed before it had appeared in Text Entry.) This is a general description on how it works: https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/keyboard-layouts.html

Comment: That make sense